# How to make this synthpop 80's style tom sound?

Tags: synthesis, samples, drum, vintage

i would like to know where the kind of drum sounds heard in this [video](https://youtu.be/E5s-TjbXJLo?t=27m13s) at 27m13s 36m56s and in particular the tom sound ("pew pew pew" tom )are from. And how to make them?

The particular tom sound can be heard very clearly at 37m42.

I was thinking about getting a LM 1 tom sound and pitching up the starting of the sample with an envelope but it looks like it is the wrong way to go. Maybe some gating involved and compression.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 80s tom sounds were all samples in either a LinnDrum or an Oberheim DMX drum machine. If those are what you want, get a gold baby sample pack or something, it will sound miles better than anything you will synthesize yourself.

It's all about layering. Te reason why 80s toms sounded so huge was that they were often doubled with several drum machines as well as recorded rototoms and regular toms. Simmons + Maybe LinnDrum + Rototom + Regular toms is what you often hear on duran duran records and suchlike.

EQ out the parts that overlap because they can drain the energy out of each other. There are lots of videos online about how to do it. The impact comes from the transient, and there's no magic trick to getting that right, though you want it to hit a split second after the sound starts. Layer lots of the same sample for more density.

Comment: Thank you I didn't know that they used to layer toms with drum synths. I'll have a look at the goldbaby packs. These machines are the only one for which I don't already have a sample pack...

Answer (score 0):

It seems to have some noise as a source on top of the usual tom architecture. Since most drum machines don't supply noise on the toms, it is a possibility that it was made using the snare channel (which does).